# Instagram /v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent endpoint doesn't return min_tag_id in pagination block

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

According to https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/, we used to get the **min_tag_id** in the pagination part of the https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag-name/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN response which we then used in the request to poll for newer posts.

As of this morning, we saw that Instagram changed the form of the pagination response. It now looks something like:

```
"pagination": {
"next_max_tag_id": "AQBy529IMOAlOvp6EI5zrYZRZbUbNW2oGQjgdvfVi5I_7wTIKzqE2nfsSBHvCkPmWOMKV7kmNcMPErenGJsbDtIk013aPZ_xo4vFYuXqtDGz3ZS0ZBrnTSjtuGjtnEOHiDJlAp8lI99AuwAgObnaf6tYhkoiDajEkg5E2zOFuDZFfQ",
"next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/enplug/media/recent?access_token=1573931388.852f6fb.2ee7fb644c5341dd813bd3bbc4c687ec&max_tag_id=AQBy529IMOAlOvp6EI5zrYZRZbUbNW2oGQjgdvfVi5I_7wTIKzqE2nfsSBHvCkPmWOMKV7kmNcMPErenGJsbDtIk013aPZ_xo4vFYuXqtDGz3ZS0ZBrnTSjtuGjtnEOHiDJlAp8lI99AuwAgObnaf6tYhkoiDajEkg5E2zOFuDZFfQ",
"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
"next_max_id": "AQBy529IMOAlOvp6EI5zrYZRZbUbNW2oGQjgdvfVi5I_7wTIKzqE2nfsSBHvCkPmWOMKV7kmNcMPErenGJsbDtIk013aPZ_xo4vFYuXqtDGz3ZS0ZBrnTSjtuGjtnEOHiDJlAp8lI99AuwAgObnaf6tYhkoiDajEkg5E2zOFuDZFfQ"
}
```

Is **min_tag_id** now deprecated? The developer docs don't mention anything about this.

Comment: _“Is min_tag_id now deprecated?”_ – sounds rather as if it was the other way around: "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",

Comment: I am having the same problem. The documentation (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) states that min_tag_id will be part of the pagination. It is unexpectedly missing.

Comment: We are also having the same issue. Can't find much information on this though.

Comment: Same problem here! Is there any way to contact the Instagram team? They simply ignore the issues submitted through the developers portal. There is also no changelog about this change, the last modification is 2015.

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to return all the media for a certain tag instead of the recent ones?

Answer (score 5):

It seems this was a temporary issue with the Instagram API and has now been resolved.

Comment: Yes, it appears that min_tag_id is back, however it was previously a Unix timestamp in microseconds, it now appears to be of this form: AQB6e6I1w2uIVlj2UIsfvd13JhT4RbZjCZZgLWl9PDVXRefheKJ4JWWvdeft_y_tSgYbiDM... (174 chars for this example)

Comment: It's actually 174 in all response I saw. Not to mention a recall generates a new min_tag_id. Kinda makes you wonder

Comment: I think these values are now cursors used in their search engine for paging through a set of search results. Combining both min_tag_id with max_tag_id in the request however does not work :(

If you input an invalid value, you get this error back:
    {"meta":{"error_type":"APIInvalidParametersError","code":400,"error_message":"min_id is not a valid cursor."}}

Comment: Is there any way to generate this new format? I used to calculate the timestamp I need but now I can't.

Comment: This problem seems to be back. We are missing the "min_tag_id" again on the responses.

Comment: It seems to be very random for us but yes, the min_tag_id is occasionally missing from the responses.

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to return all the media for a certain tag instead of the recent ones?

Answer (score 3):

So upon further investigation, I noticed that you can use the **id** of the newest post to effectively filter out older posts from the https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag-name/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN response, which now always returns the last 20 posts.

An **id** of a instagram post typically looks like *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyy* where *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx* is essentially the **min_tag_id** that used to be returned in the pagination block and *yyyyyyyyyy* is the user's id.

So you can extract the *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx* part of a post's id(*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyy*) and do a comparison to see if it is larger than the previous *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx* that you were keeping track of to retrieve newer posts.

Comment: I had tried this and it seemed that API was ignoring it and I was getting a response with the same result each time - with or without the &min_tag_id (where min_tag_id is the 'xxxxx' component mentioned above). Perhaps Instagram has now fixed based on the answer from Yousef. If min_tag_id is back, then I will just use it..

Comment: You can't use the 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from the post's id to page through the response anymore. I actually meant that you can use the 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' to manually filter out posts by extracting 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyy'. 

You actually get errors when you use 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' as min_tag_id. Something like "min_tag_id must not be a media id".

They have started using a new format for min_tag_id and max_tag_id as mentioned in some of the comments here.

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to return all the media for a certain tag instead of the recent ones?