# Instagram API /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent changed behaviour

Tags: instagram-api

I worked several times with this endpoint and it seems that since this week when I pass a max_id value an error is thrown, it says:

```
{
    "meta":  {
        "error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError",
        "code": 400,
        "error_message": "max_id must not be a media id."
    }
}
```

I have no idea where to find if api has changed behaviour or simply it's broken. 
Guys, do you have any idea?

Another error that I've found is the order of returned Medias when I query this endpoint. Here's a sample data:

```
#sample error
[
    Media: 1220853576116214570_1383882821
    Media: 1220853572180739674_233961632
    Media: 1220853571106323542_44255974
    Media: 1220853327487332588_16383867
    Media: 1220853529276039536_37204591
    Media: 1220853517236612185_1342227858
    Media: 1220853478513480317_596571
    Media: 1220853329006327307_299159508
    Media: 1220853296836482014_1829274963
    Media: 1220853282356978078_1498664215
    Media: 1220853191933038656_528166155
    Media: 1220481246711237359_211289081  #MEDIA INCORRECT ORDER
    Media: 1220853144521663282_3026017167
    Media: 1220853127735637950_619046756
    Media: 1220853103550902683_2074401387
    Media: 1220853106444172011_3020165605
    Media: 1220449359646948005_208916789  #MEDIA INCORRECT ORDER
    Media: 1220853071011680880_596571
    Media: 1220852985861033044_446238634
    Media: 1220852995848611111_3098675456
    Media: 1220852944343050919_1126655937
    Media: 1220852926209616200_327453609
    Media: 1220852902671104371_351483533
    Media: 1220852898165133786_207127275
    Media: 1220852887618705294_1736270372
    Media: 1220852850174855566_1133338201
    Media: 1220852831895483805_30557620
    Media: 1220851564341433250_1460935835
    Media: 1220852721064734213_14247170
    Media: 1220852681564341476_1329013696
    Media: 1220852647186623946_2143587522
    Media: 1220852634988856098_6331807
    Media: 1220852621030972511_530287550
]
```

**Edit**: I've just checked that python instagram's client has been deprecated 9 days ago, and there's a lot of stackoverflow questions about api behaviour's from 23-march. A lot of coincidences

[Instagram /v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent endpoint doesn't return min_tag_id in pagination block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166770/instagram-v1-tags-tag-name-media-recent-endpoint-doesnt-return-min-tag-id-i)

[Error 400: Bad request while fetching json data from instagram api via coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328189/error-400-bad-request-while-fetching-json-data-from-instagram-api-via-coldfusio)

[API Tags endpoint error - min_id is not a valid cursor for this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416427/api-tags-endpoint-error-min-id-is-not-a-valid-cursor-for-this-tag)

**Edit 2:** count parameter can't be greater than 33, omitted otherwise. In another words, max records per page number is 33

**Edit 3:** Python client's broken since 1st of June due another undocumented behaviour change

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 194, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 186, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 148, in _do_api_request
    obj = self.root_class.object_from_dictionary(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/models.py", line 88, in object_from_dictionary
    for comment in entry['comments']['data']:
KeyError: 'data'
```

**Edit 3 solved [here](https://github.com/filepicker/python-instagram/commit/f8d6a6f2f73e46110175f293bff99f0c654e9473)**

Comment: There is definitely something that has changed/broken with their API during this week. First off, they have changed min/max_tag_id to some hashed string instead of the numeric value they previously had. If you try to pass the old numeric value, you will get the error message you describe here. New requests to the API will only give the hashed string in return, so you can use that instead. But there is something wrong with max_tag_id, it just doesn't work like before. I have filed a report, but I'm not that hopeful they will answer it, considering how little they communicate with their users...

Comment: Is there any way to check api status (like Twitter) or report any issue or something like that?

Comment: You can report an issue here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/. I have done that, but I'm not to hopeful in getting a response from them

Comment: @Joel if they answer keep us informed. It really breaks all our app logic and it is not cool that min_tag_id from first request pagination returns 38w old data.

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis Still haven't heard anything so I doubt they will get back to me. :( You should also file a report here https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Comment: @Joel made a report. But this all is very confusing, how such serious company can make such changes without notifying and even having edited documentation with those changes.

Comment: I get `next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead`, But when I use `max_tag_id` I get thir errror message: `max_id must not be a media id.`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're passing a media id as pagination. You can't do that anymore since Instagram changed the pagination values. It used to be a media id, but now is a string.

When you do the request, you'll receive an json like this:

```
{
    pagination: {
        next_max_tag_id: ...,
        deprecation_warning: "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
        next_max_id: ...,
        next_min_id: ...,
        min_tag_id: ...
        ...
    },
    meta: {
        ...
    },
    data: {
        ...
    }
}
```

Just use the `next_max_id` value as `max_tag_id` in your request. That should works.

Comment: Ok, first: is this change documented? Second: what about if I want to search from a Max_id to the past as I've used this endpoint until it's broken?

Comment: Sadly it is not documented... That change occurred a couple of weeks ago. There's no changelog and since the field name is still the same and just the value is different, it is not in the documentation..

I'm afraid that you can't search for media before a max_id if this max_id is a media_id... You'll need to going backward using the new max_id provided in the pagination until you get where you want.

Comment: I get `next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead`, But when I use `max_tag_id` I get thir errror message: `max_id must not be a media id.`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this until Instagram actually responds anyone is to use the old and deprecated `next_max_id` or `next_max_tag_id`.
It seems somehow that `max_tag_id` has disappeared completely in the request response and been replaced with `next_max_tag_id`.

`/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token={access-token}&next_max_id={next_max_id}`

Comment: It doesn't work, the parameter's omitted. It returns the same result that if you hadn't pass it

Comment: I get `next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead`, But when I use `max_tag_id` I get thir errror message: `max_id must not be a media id.`