# Instagram API : missing elements in json response

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram's [Get Recent Media](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) endpoint to get images and videos from tag. Based on the documentation, here's what a `video` media `json` looks like (skipped other fields for brevity):

```
{
    "type": "video",
    "videos": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 480
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
        }
    }
}
```

So, for every media `json` with `type=video`, there should be a `videos` element. I then tried a request with `quakeroats` as tag, following is the url:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/quakeroats/media/recent?access_token=<access_token>
```

It returned a list of media with below as one of the medias:

```
{
    "id": "1457772143914843055_4607772970",
    "type": "video",
    "created_time": "1488000003",
    "images": {
        "thumbnail": {
            "height": 150,
            "width": 150,
            "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/16788643_240567646348968_4950335324904488960_n.jpg"
        },
        "low_resolution": {
            "height": 320,
            "width": 320,
            "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/16788643_240567646348968_4950335324904488960_n.jpg"
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "height": 480,
            "width": 480,
            "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/16788643_240567646348968_4950335324904488960_n.jpg"
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "username": "aslapesetme.43kilo",
        "full_name": "\u0130nan\u0131rsan Olur",
        "id": "4607772970",
        "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/16230854_382859295410786_1559541722264895488_a.jpg"
    },
    "user_has_liked": false,
    "link": "https://www.instagram.com/p/BQ7DAqRgPuv/",
    "attribution": null,
    "location": null,
    "likes": {
        "count": 22
    },
    "comments": {
        "count": 0
    },
    "caption": {
        "text": "\ud83d\udca08:00\ud83d\udca0 kahvalt\u0131:\n-50 gr. Yulaf\n-1 bardak s\u00fct\n-1 porsiyon meyve ve 1 \u00e7ay ka\u015f\u0131\u011f\u0131 kakao nibs\nNefiiss \ud83d\ude0b \u00e7ok \u015f\u00fck\u00fcr bizi doyuran rabbimize \ud83d\ude4f\ud83c\udffb Ayr\u0131ca frambuaz ve elman\u0131n sadece renk uyumu de\u011fil tat uyumu da m\u00fcthi\u015f deneyin \ud83d\udc7b\n#healtyfood#healthybreakfast#quakeroats#quakeroatmeal#quakerporridge#milk#apple#raspberries#framboise#ahududu#yulaflapasi#yulafezmesi#porridgelover#porridge#cacaonibs#diyet#diyetkardesligi#diyethesaplaritakiplesiyor#inan\u0131rsanolur#sadeceinan#eceilezayifliyorum#doganinguzelligi#dogalbeslen#kendinisev#benimkahvaltim#nofilter#greentea#whitetea#ginger#hediyenhayatinolsun",
        "from": {
            "username": "aslapesetme.43kilo",
            "full_name": "\u0130nan\u0131rsan Olur",
            "id": "4607772970",
            "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/16230854_382859295410786_1559541722264895488_a.jpg"
        },
        "created_time": "1488000003",
        "id": "17849784529188561"
    },
    "filter": "Normal"
}
```

It seems to have `type` set to `video`, however, there is no `videos` element. Additionally, media link (https://www.instagram.com/p/BQ7DAqRgPuv/) seems to be pointing to an image and not a video.

Looks like it's either a bug or a recent change in the API response format (I am seeing the errors in import script over the last few days only) or both.

Has anyone else observed this? Also, is this something I should submit to Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

currently in API if `type="video"` and no "videos" key means it is multi-image post.

(looks like it is a bug and Instagram may change it eventually)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this also, when I was trying to update some of my code to work with their new multi-image (or video) capability. Instagram now allows you to upload multiple images as a single post, and then you can swipe between them in the UI. It looks like this hasn't really been considered in the API though, and so multi-item posts are returning as `type=video` (when they should be `type=image` if they're all images, or perhaps `type=multi` or something new).

More annoying for my use-case is that they are also not including the required data about each different media item included in the single post, so I can't fully re-create a multi-item post, since I don't know anything other than the first image in the "deck".

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has changed its behaviour without any notification.
It isn't the first time:[Instagram API /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent changed behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354495/instagram-api-tags-tag-name-media-recent-changed-behaviour)
I'm mantaining a fork of official client that deal with this issue (and the other)

`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/MabrianOfficial/python-instagram.git`