# API Tags endpoint error - min_id is not a valid cursor for this tag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Since a few days ago we've been getting an error response from Instagram API - it complains that we are using an invalid cursor 'min_id' when accessing the Tags endpoint.

Thing is we don't use 'min_id'. We use 'min_tag_id', which according to the documentation ([deprecated](https://www.instagram.com/developer/deprecated/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) & [current](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent)) is a valid cursor for this endpoint.

Doing some research I see that some people have been getting unexpected errors too (though different ones) around this week.

Example API request (plug an access token and paste in a browser to see for yourselves):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&min_tag_id=AQCvuinNA31T_hoSa-RaCsQigBknfYaBv2_VcCn1kp4MX5whyr7v7AfpOzio8E4lcQ9TZIKZbN_ZAqEmuzmslq8qMmFTQF-1ocNntqDIjlN4va4GxocNeBxmo29nXEOjKIRVvce5PuvoXk3MY9nuNd6hbxFj7TW_FEWTWpdx9FNzEQ
```

And the response:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APIInvalidParametersError","code":400,"error_message":"min_id is not a valid cursor for this tag."}}
```

Any idea?

Comment: same here! can't really find anything else on the internet regarding this issue. Please leave updates if you find anything useful and I'll also do the same.

Comment: I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166770/instagram-v1-tags-tag-name-media-recent-endpoint-doesnt-return-min-tag-id-in

they say the reason for this is because the min_tag_id supplied is invalid.

Comment: I tried manually getting the recent media for a specific tag alone and then copied the min_tag_id and used it with another request but still the same error. I guess this is really a problem with the API.

Comment: I have also contacted IG support about this. From past experience it will take them around 2 weeks to reply, so I'm hoping the solution will arrive from another place.. Glad to know I'm not alone. I will post updates.

Comment: The format of min_tag_id changed last week. The new min_tag_id is a hashed string that contains information about what tag it can be used with. So I cannot send min_tag_id from a query belonging to tag #sweden into a query with tag #norway. Then I will get that error. BUT! There is something wrong with the API, because all of a sudden, what was a valid min_tag_id, can suddenly become invalid in a later request (to the same tag). And you'll get that same error message even if it is a request to the same tag. So something is definitely broken or there has been large undocumented changes

Comment: I've also created a question about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354495/instagram-api-tags-tag-name-media-recent-changed-behaviour

Comment: We are also getting intermittent errors with min_tag_ids that are returned from a previous request so should be valid.

Comment: I have the same issue but not able to reproduce. Is it possible the issue was resolved but I'm now stuck with some min_tag_ids and I have no way to recover a valid min_tag_id for them? WHY NOT JUST USE A TIMESTAMP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this is how I solved it - after waiting for a few days and seeing that nothing happens then I have deleted all min_tag_id values that I have in store. I also altered my app logic to deal with the situation (in my case when there's no min_tag_id then I load some historical posts, which I commented out for this fix).

I ran the import process and this repopulated the min_tag_id field. The new values have no problems. Either they fixed the issue or the un-tagging thing didn't happen to me again yet.

So far so good. Will post updates if any.

Answer (score 3):

I got this response from Instagram when enquiring about invalid pagination tokens

> "Thanks for the report. We are aware of this issue and it happens when
>   pictures are un-tagged (e.g. The comment with the tag is deleted). We
>   are working on a fix but I don’t have an eta to share at the moment."